# How to remove unneeded parenthesis in a string?

Tags: php

I have a string containing a mathematical expression, like `(21)*(4+2)`. For the purposes of computing, I need to "simplify" it so that it doesn't contain any number between expression (i.e. `(21)*(4+2) => 21*(4+2)`). I have no idea of how to do it (I thought of something with regex replaces, but I'm not very good at handling it).

Comment: Is this for an assignment or something? parentheses around a single number won't alter the result of the expression.

Comment: Try to match them like this `\(\d+\)`. If it matches, remove the parenthesis.

Comment: I think that comment has been removed. Anyways, here's an example link http://codepad.org/pXQdiuak

Comment: @nickb I didn't see that comment, my mistake.

Comment: I know parentheses around a number won't alter the result, but I found out my script can't handle them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you can do an algorithm something like this:

```
$str = "(21)*(4+2)";
//split above to array of characters
$arr = str_split($str);

foreach($arr as $i => $char) {
   if character is opening parenthesis {
     get all characters in a string until closing parnethesis is found
   endif }

   if the string you received from above contains only digits 
   (means it has no expression i.e. +,-,/,%,*) then remove the first and last 
   characters of the above string which are the parenthesis and append the 
   string to the final string.
}
```

Comment: Seems way more complicated than necessary. A simple regular expression replacement would work just fine.

Comment: thats why this is called doing it using algorithm :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it seems to me that I accidently solved the problem(so far, the `preg_replace` works for me):

```
echo preg_replace( "/\((\d+)\)/", "$1", $eq );
```

It doesn't take into account the decimals, I think. The sample equation and output it generates is [here](http://codepad.org/SLwxPx4A) on [codepad](http://codepad.org/SLwxPx4A).

For decimals, I used a `[\d\.]+` in the regex. It seems to be working.

```
echo preg_replace( "/\(([\d\.]+)\)/", "$1", $eq );
```

Another [link](http://codepad.org/SsML2F3Z).